# Custom post types not imported properly

Tags: custom-post-types, import

I've registered a custom post type:

```
function create_gallery_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'sim_gallery',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Sim Gallery' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_position' => 10,
      'description' => "Post for displaying gallery"
    )
  );
}
```

Now I'm trying to import the content from my staging server to my dev server.
During the import process, I get the feedback that it failed to import all my custom post.

So clicking 'Sim Gallery' in the left navigation panel, shows zero posts.

But if I look at the database, wp_posts, I can actually see the posts.
If I try to create a post with a name that is already registered, I get `somename-2` where `-2` indicates that a post by the same name is already registered.

So my question is:

1) Why does the wp import function say that it failed to import my cistom posts?
2) Why are my custo mpost not shown in the post listing in the backend?

Comment: Why not import data using a sql dump ?

Comment: Because exporting wia WP is a lot easier than having to login to server and get access to PHPMyAdmin through cPanel.

Comment: easier is not necessarily proper.

Comment: @soju - FYI, doing a SQL dump to export data is considered last resort. It is not the recommended first step.

Comment: Where did you read this ???

Comment: @Steve False. Doing a SQL dump of posts/content is fine. Doing a SQL dump of settings/options will probably get you into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the underscore from your Custom Post Type name?  I ran into an issue a few weeks ago that was resolved when I changed to only alphabetical characters.

Comment: hmm.... that defeats the purpose of avoiding getting the custom attribs in the drop down list. But I'll do a test with this and see if this solves the issue. If yes, then I consider this a "bug".

Comment: It's not really a bug, because the actual name of the post type ('sim_gallery') is only used internally.  If you change it, of course, you'll need to change the post_type field in the database to match as well.