# When importing - failed to import: Invalid post type, feedback

Tags: comments, import, xml

I am attempting to import a site using XML generated by WordPress.com

All the posts and media seem to import, but the comments fail with errors

```
Failed to import “Sarah Toon - 2015-10-10 08:29:30”: Invalid post type feedback
Failed to import “Kylie - 2015-10-10 08:34:50”: Invalid post type feedback
Failed to import “Sophie Ward - 2015-10-10 08:36:22”: Invalid post type feedback
```

Reading other posts, here on WordPress.SE none of them have an accepted answer.  The closest I could find is [Custom post types not imported properly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49531/custom-post-types-not-imported-properly) but that is about posts, not comments.

Can someone get me started on solving this please?

Comment: do you import daTa from the `WordPress.com`?

Comment: @prosti "I am attempting to import a site using XML generated by WordPress.com" :P

Comment: I was just looking at this again because someone voted for it and I now see why I was confused.  There is a missing comma.  It should read "invalid post type, feedback" ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is you're trying to import posts with a post type of `feedback`, but there is no such post type registered on your install of WordPress.

Quick-and-easy fix is to register one:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    register_post_type( 'feedback', [
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => 'Feedback',
            'name'          => 'Feedback',
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Place it in your theme's `functions.php`, or in a MU plugin (eg. `wp-content/mu-plugins/feedback.php`).

Comment: Thanks...I knew it was something like that but it is beyond my WP skills :P  Testing it, will accept if it works.

Answer (score 3):

The Jetpack plugin creates a custom post type of feedback when active.
You may need to just install that plugin first (as I did).
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating a website from wordpress.com and I had same problem.

I've solved first installing the Jetpack plugin, then activating the Contact Form module in this url **[yoursite.com]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules** and finally doing the import.

Hope that helps to someone!